# How to change the color for the first and last tab in TabLayout setting up with ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-xml, android-tablayout

I am trying to implement a looping `ViewPager`. I did it by adding two dummy pages in the first and last place of my pages. And i am using `TabLayout` with it as a page indicator, that's why i wanted to set the first and last tab to transparent and disabled. 
This is my current xml code for TabLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabDots"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />
```

And this is the drawable xml for `TabLayout`:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_default"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"/>

<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_selected"
    android:state_first="false"
    android:state_last="false"
    android:state_selected="true"/>
```

I have tried to use state_first and state_last but it is not functioning.

This is a tricking method for me but i have searched some tutorials to implement Looping `ViewPager`. Most of them require at least 4 pages which is not suitable in my case because the pages in `ViewPager` is dynamic, could have less than 4 pages.
Please help.

This is my adapter class:

```
    public class ShopPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    // This holds all the currently displayable views, in order from left to right.
    private ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        int index = views.indexOf(object);
        if (index == -1)
            return POSITION_NONE;
        else
            return index;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View v = views.get(position);
        if(v.getParent() != null)
            ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v);
        container.addView(v);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView(views.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return views.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    public int addView(View v) {
        return addView(v, views.size());
    }

    public int addView(View v, int position) {
        views.add(position, v);
        return position;
    }

    public int removeView(ViewPager pager, View v) {
        return removeView(pager, views.indexOf(v));
    }

    public int removeView(ViewPager pager, int position) {
        pager.setAdapter(null);
        views.remove(position);
        pager.setAdapter(this);

        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position) {
        return views.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the java code for your pagerAdapter class? and also where it's being used (activity, fragment, etc). you may have to do it programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tableLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        switch (tab.getPosition())
        {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    } 
});
```

Comment: It seems like your answer format is wrong.
But what i am trying to do is the make the first and last tab "transparent" no matter it is selected or not. Can i achieve this using tabSelectedListener?

Comment: Well, i did it using this method, 
Basically i set the icon for middle tabs and transparent icon for first and last tabs in both Selected and Unselected method. And select all tabs once (it will go back to first page because last page is the dummy page for first page). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You want something along the lines of:

```
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new ShopPageAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);        

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
LinearLayout firstAndLastTabs = ((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0));
firstAndLastTabs.setEnabled(false);
firstAndLastTabs.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(getResources()
            .getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
firstAndLastTabs.getChildAt(0).setClickable(false);

firstAndLastTabs.getChildAt(tabLayout.getTabCount() - 1).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent);
    firstAndLastTabs.getChildAt(tabLayout.getTabCount() - 1).setClickable(false);
```

the background color of the first and last tabs are going to be transparent and click events will not be triggered when both those tabs are clicked.

Comment: This is not viable in my case, i set the page indicator(tabLayout) using tabBackground. I get null when i am trying to use getIcon() for my tab. Should i change it?

Comment: oh right, it's not visible because 0 makes it so transparent it disappears, try with an alpha of 90.

Comment: sorry, i misread your comment, i thought you said "visible", i have added some modification, try again and let me know.

Comment: It returns null for this line: firstAndLastTabs.getChildAt(0)
But i have fixed it using @shenweiwei method. Thanks for the help anyways